# How to get the data out from Altera DE1 kit

Tags: io, fpga

I am now using Altera DE 1 kit to do some calculation and I have no idea on how to retrieve the output result of the calculation. Here is my cases:

I had inputted 2 set of data into ROM and let the Altera DE1 kit do the calculation and how I suppose to get the result so I can analysis it.

Any suggestion or methods to do so? Please provide the answer in more clearer ways as I am a beginner in FPGA.

Answer (score 1):

you could use rs232 to output this data to a computer. I think there are some ip available for rs232 you could use.

Also in a more advanced way you could attach the reaults memory to a avalon-mm bus and read it through systemconsole using some tcl code.

Comment: is it possible that i able to save the answer in ram and retrieve the content in the ram? like store it in .mif file and retrieve the .mif file from the fpga?

Comment: I know that it is possible to save all the content in the ram and you can hook this ram using avalon memory mapped bus to a tag to avalon bridge. Using this component you can use system console to read all the data from the ram.